# configurable routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, routes

I'm working on a small rails gem where my config/routes.rb looks like this.

```
    resources :blog_posts do

            resources :blog_comments
            resources :blog_images

            collection do
                    get :drafts
            end
    end
```

I guess it works as i should, but I would like :blog_posts to be something configurable. Thus not forcing the gem to be hard coded into using the url /blog_posts/

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into "mounting" of routes so that users of your gem can mount your engine's routes at a point of their choosing. I suggest having a look at device gem.

Comment: Yeah - I guess mounting is what I'm looking for. Although I'm not sure what the device gem has to do with it

Comment: @marcus device pops up immediately in the mind as a gem that you could look at for an example, i meant.